# Stream binary file from MySQL to download with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, binary, download

I have Excel spreadsheets stored in a MySQL table longblob field. I need to retrieve this data and then stream it to the user as a downloadable file, preferably without writing it to disk first.

Possible?

Edit - Eh, just figured it out... Posted in answer below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
function getfile($blockid)
{
    global $msa_db;
    $sql = "select filename, filedata from blocks where blockid = '$blockid'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql, $msa_db);
    $result['filename'] = mysql_result($query,0,0);
    $result['filedata'] = mysql_result($query,0,1);
    return $result;

}

function download($fileinfo)
{
    $file = base64_decode($fileinfo['filedata']);
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache private");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$fileinfo['filename']);
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header('Content-Length: '. strlen($file));
    echo $file;
    exit;
}

$fileinfo = getfile($blockid);

download($fileinfo);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This might be useful one day :o)

Answer (score 2):

Just got the solution

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/831185/CREATE-DOWNLOAD-ZIP-FILE-USING-PHP

```
    $data = base64_decode($data);

    header("Cache-Control: no-cache private");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename='".$identifier.".zip'");      
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header('Content-Length: '. strlen($data));      
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");

    ob_clean();
    flush();

    echo $data;
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. How does it improve over the accepted solution from 7 years ago?