# Intentionally Slow Down HTML/PHP Page Load to Test

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, testing, load-testing

I'm curious if there exists a method to intentionally slow the page load?

I'm testing my HTML & PHP pages on my local host right now, and I want to see how my loading gif etc will perform when the page load is slower.

I realize this is a rare request as most developers are only concerned with speeding *up* page loads, but I thought there might be a method, using either javascript/jQuery or PHP, to do something like this for testing purposes.

Thanks for any help!

Note: I'm testing on MAMP, so that's Apache server running on Mac OS 10.7

Comment: Well, you could always replace your network connection with a 3200 baud modem....

Comment: If you want to slowdown every requests (including images), this will have to be on the server or OS level; which server / OS are you using ?

Comment: @mblase75 - +1 and props for a wicked sense of humour ;)

Comment: @arnaud576875 - I'm using MAMP, so that's Apache, and Mac OS 10.7

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use php's [`sleep($seconds)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) function to slow down a page load. However, you would need to turn [implicit output buffer flushing to "on"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-implicit-flush.php) with `ob_implicit_flush(true);` if you want anything to be sent to the user's browser before the page is done being processed. Otherwise your page won't have ANY contents until it's done loading. Calling sleep alone won't do the trick.

Comment: Excellent answer. I'll look at the link you provided. I'm sure this question is answered at the link, but is `ob_implicit_flush(true);` part of `php.ini`?

Comment: Never mind, I should have checked the link first. It's called in the PHP file itself. Thanks, I'll give this a go!

Comment: No problem! Let me know how this goes.

Answer (score 16):

In Chrome, you can simulate a slow Internet connection with the developer tools. under the "Network" Tab on the far right. You can use a preset like "Fast G3" or can create your own with exact numbers for upload, download and ping.

[image]

Reference: https://helpdeskgeek.com/networking/simulate-slow-internet-connection-testing/

Comment: Firefox has something similar under Network. There is a dropdown saying "No throttling" by default, but you can slow the page down intentionally by choosing another option.

Answer (score 4):

[Moussa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/943019/moussa) has the right idea. The best way to test a slow page load is to use Chrome's developer tools. Select the network tab, and then click the dropdown that says "No throttling". Then change the page to your desired speed.

This way is superior to using the sleep function because you don't have to mess with any code and then remember to take it out. If you want to change the speed, just change the throttling level and you're set.

For more information on throttling [check out the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode#network-conditions).

Comment: This is nice feature...!

Answer (score 3):

This is what I would try:
Use a php resource as source of the image:

```
<img src="images/gifLoager.php" />
```

in gifLoader.php, read your image file, output it byte by byte with a delay in the loop.

```
$fp = fopen( $path, 'rb');
while(!feof($fp)) {
        print(fread($fp, 1024));
        flush();
        Sleep(1);
     }
fclose($fp);
```

Don't forget to appropriately set the headers before outputting the binary data.

**Referrences:**

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563069/stream-binary-file-from-mysql-to-download-with-php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php
http://www.gamedev.net/topic/427622-php-and-file-streaming-script-with-resume-capability/
```

**UPDATE 2015-04-09**
Use Chrome 'Device Mode':
This tool has a network throttling feature that allows you to see how your page may render on a device with a slow network bandwidth. It has many other features that allow you to emulate features on various devices such as screen size and touch.

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode

Comment: This sounds like an incredibly creative method, and I like it. I'm wondering however: Would this not be delaying the load of the loader gif image itself? I want to test the loader gif and other loader setups by delaying the load of the page contents; Not the loader gif itself. I'm thinking however, that I could easily change your code to delay the load of one, or more than one, of the images on the page; Thus delaying the page load and demonstrating the loader gif etc. Am I right?

Comment: You're correct. I guess I misunderstood your question. My answer went more toward delaying the loading of the image. You could use the same concept for any other resource, however.

This is obviously a hack. A better way would be to use a "Network Emulator". Such tools are very common, and they allow you to emulate a low bandwidth network. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094760/network-tools-that-simulate-slow-network-connection.

Comment: Thanks. I've investigated this, and unless I'm mistaken, none of the resources provided at the link you provided, are for Mac. Do you know of a good open source Network Emulator? Do you know if there is a method in MAMP, or an add-on for MAMP, that would mimic a slow network connection, or high traffic?

Comment: Please see the resources shown in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130354/how-do-i-simulate-a-low-bandwidth-high-latency-environment

Answer (score 2):

A little bit of JS setTimeout can do the trick

```
setTimeout(function()
{
    // Delayed code in here
    alert('You waited 5 seconds to see me'); // Waits 5 seconds, then alerts this
}, 5000); // 5000 = 5 seconds
```

Comment: It's kinda creepy that someone with a name almost like mine answers this question at the same time, lol.

Comment: @Joe - This does seem the easiest, provided it will work. What should I wrap the `setTimeout()` around?

Comment: Of course it works :P Put it inside a `<script type="text/javascript">CODE HERE</script>` and then anything you want to be delayed, put that where the "Delayed code in here" comment is. See modified post for basic example. For example, presumably you have your loading GIF visible by default, so put the code to hide it inside the timeout, and it will wait 5 seconds, then hide your loading GIF.

Comment: @Joe - Oh, I understand what you're saying. Isn't that just delaying the removal of the loading gif? It's not really mimicking a slow page load, is it?

Comment: Well, that really depends on how you set it up :) If you have JS that runs on page load, you can put that inside the delay and it'll execute later. If you're looking to stall the PHP script finishing, then you want `sleep` as Cyclone mentioned. Both are right, it's just which way you want to do it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sleep()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.sleep.php):

```
<?php
// Delays for 10 seconds.
sleep(10);
?>

...
html here
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Call [`sleep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) in your PHP code to delay the request to the server.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [sloppy local web proxy](http://www.dallaway.com/sloppy/) to slow down your connection (it's in JAVA, so it'll probably run on your devel machine. You might also want to turn off mod_deflate for testing purposes, if you want so how your browser responds to slow HTML load (for example, dynamicly sized HTML tables, etc)

Also, see [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/861/how-can-i-simulate-a-slow-connection-for-page-load) on webmasters.stackexchange.com