# Local testing - intentionally slowing down loading to test page behaviour

Tags: performance, testing, pageload, page-load-time

I am developing my websites locally with MAMP. But I would like to know how they will act in the 'real world'.

Is there a way how I can **intentionally** slow down page load to a more common internet connection speed? I am mostly concerned on how well my websites perform looking at HTML requests (scripts, images, sprites, etc.) and lacy loading.

The only thing I found by googling was this: [Intentionally Slow Down HTML/PHP Page Load to Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405987/intentionally-slow-down-html-php-page-load-to-test).
I don't want to **stop** page load though, I just want to make it **slower**.

Thanks!

### EDIT

For googlers - one of the answers at [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405987/intentionally-slow-down-html-php-page-load-to-test) recommended [Deeelay.me](http://www.deelay.me/) service, which is exactly what I was looking for at the time.

Answer (score 0):

set up local proxy and set transfer rate as desired. it may be apache but for sure you can find something simpler with google