# How to limit the load speed of a website?

Tags: php, performance, connection

I have a website and I'd like to "bug" it by limiting the load speed (like a 56ko/S connection bandwidth lol)

Is it possible in PHP ? maybe with Header ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes sorry for my english :p The duplicate is what I was looking for, but I didn't how to mention it. thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, while downloading or processing something you may add a sleep or usleep.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7406036/6288442

> You can use php's sleep($seconds) function to slow down a page load.
>   However, you would need to turn implicit output buffer flushing to
>   "on" with ob_implicit_flush(true); if you want anything to be sent to
>   the user's browser before the page is done being processed. Otherwise
>   your page won't have ANY contents until it's done loading. Calling
>   sleep alone won't do the trick.

Comment: Thank you very much :) And all the best for 2018. Cheeeers

Comment: cheers :) @Didier

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the scenario.

If you want to "test" your code while you're in development, you should use a browser that allows you to set the connection speed. Almost all browsers provide such features, for example, Chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/network-conditions.

If you want to write something like an automated test, it depends on the infrastructure, i.e. on the webserver.

Like for Apache, there is a module available to decrease the connection's speed for certain requests, mod_ratelimit: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ratelimit.html. Install it and configure it for your needs. You could for example, activate it before the test, do the test, then deactivate it again on you local test environment.