# How to go about protecting files from unauthorized downloads

Tags: php, mysql, apache, download

I am creating a membership site using PHP and a MySQL database, I have the means for users to log in using their username and password. All pretty standard stuff.

I even got the system in place to allow registered users to download sample video files. That works great too.

The problem, however, is that anyone who can figure out the file system can directly download these files.

Say we have the main folder that contains the video content called 'videos' and inside 'videos' we have sub-folders such as 'planes', 'trains' and 'automobiles' with separate folders inside each of them (such as 'jets', 'prop' and 'spy' for 'planes') with specific videos for each sub-category.

So if someone knows the file system, they can simply type `https://www.myvideosite.com/videos/planes/jets/f15.wmv` and download to their heart's content provided they know the filenames. (As you can see, I have a secure connection and it's on an Apache server running Linux.)

This is a major security hole that I would like to plug before it is discovered. I have researched the .htaccess thing but my efforts with that often lead the entire 'videos' folder from being inaccessible (I will admit, I am new to all of this!).

I have also read about placing my video files outside of the site root folder, but that looks even more confusing.

Simply put, how on earth can I disable downloading by people who are not members but who may discover (through whatever means) what the file system is? This should be simple, in my opinion, but alas, I am not finding a solid answer.

Comment: Stream it from PHP - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563069/stream-binary-file-from-mysql-to-download-with-php etc.

Comment: Are the users just downloading these files, or do you need to make them accessible for viewing in browser?

Comment: @Mike Brant The files are strictly for download. Though now that you mention it the dialog box does give the option to open in the browser.

Comment: @Aerik I am using the MySQLi extension, I think that code you recommended was original MySQL. But even so, how does that prevent one from typing the complete path and filename into a browser and downloading without going to my site?

Comment: The point of my comment wasn't that you should put the files in MySQL, it was that you should mask the path with PHP (the path can even be outside of your public directory) and only allow authenticated users to download the files.

Answer (score 4):

You can protect your video folder with an .htaccess file and 'route' all the requests through a php script:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?file_id=$1 [L]
```

And do the authentication in the index.php

```
session_start();
// get filename from database or somewhere else
$filename = getFilename($_GET["file_id"]);

if ($_SESSION["is_logged_in"]) {
    readfile($filename);
}
```

Comment: You might want to add validation to make sure someone doesn't add something like `../foo/bar.file`

Comment: That works +1.  With readfile() you can also store your videos below the webroot without worrying about .htaccess

Comment: @Class Interesting...could you elaborate?

Comment: @James L Would you be so kind as to shed a little more light on your reply?

Comment: @Class, thats an simple example. (my idea: do it with an ID and do an DB lookup for id <=> filename).

Comment: @take I added the .htaccess file with the code you supplied above, now I receive this error: `Not Found

The requested URL /404.shtml was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

Comment: @mileaminute posted answer as reply

Comment: @mileaminute its adding a regular expression/checking against a db/checking via a switch or any other way you feel best checking the file name and if it is good download/show file otherwise show error message.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer if you are having issues with .htaccess

Ok, so if you are serving this is public_html, go to it's parent directory create a directory name "videos".  (if not in public_html, you may have to add some ../ to the path).  The pathinfo takes care of the validation issue and will return only a file name if someone tries to sneak a path in there.  If you name it download.php, this:

download.php?video=fun.mp4

will load a file called fun.mp4 from the video directory.

```
<?php
// do your user authentication
$video_directory = "../videos/";
$file = pathinfo($_GET["video"], PATHINFO_BASENAME);
if( $user_is_logged_in )
{
    if( file_exists( $file ) readfile( $video_directory . $file );
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for that, I will look at that now. Tell me, will this prevent people from downloading files by typing the path and filename directly into the browser?

Answer (score 0):

USe simple .htaccess/htpasswd authentication, digest or basic:

http://www.askapache.com/online-tools/htpasswd-generator/

Comment: Actually, I use authentication via a MySQL database and not htpassword as the research I did said that it was not secure. Additionally, it does not allow the user to log out which was not what I wanted. I simply want to block access from anyone typing in the full path of a file into their browser which would automatically allow them to download it.