# PHP: make uploaded file in root folder (not in public_html) accessible only for logged in user?

Tags: php, security, file-upload, download

I made an upload form and stored files in (root) '../upload_file' folder

the problem is how authorized (logged in) user only can download that uploaded files? because browser cant handle root url like: www.web.com/../upload_file/test.pdf

please Im newbie

thanks :D

---

Ok, I want make this clear. Actualy my question is similar to: [How to go about protecting files from unauthorized downloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078973/how-to-go-about-protecting-files-from-unauthorized-downloads)

where is unsolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a php script that will authenticate the user and then output the contents of the uploaded file in the php script. Make sure you do not echo anything out before setting the headers of the output file. There should be code somewhere on how to load the contents of a file into a variable.

```
$fileContents = file_get_contents("test.pdf");

header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate");
header("content-disposition: attachment; filename=test.pdf");
header("content-type: application/pdf");
header("content-length: " . strlen($fileContents));

//output file contents
echo $fileContents;
```

The users should never have access directly to the upload folder.

Comment: Look up PHP function file_get_contents to read the contents of a file into $fileContents

Comment: how output the contents of the uploaded file in the php script?

Comment: using the echo command after setting the headers like I did above in the code snippet.

Comment: $fileContents = file_get_contents ("test.pdf");

Comment: I fixed the script as I had the content-disposition set to inline rather than attachment.

Comment: OK I understand, is before echo command I can add if_user_logged_in script??

Comment: I have the check if_user_is_logged_in at the very top of the script before the header statements. I redirect the user to another page if they are not logged in

Answer (score 0):

Access control depends on your server operating system and server, like Windows Server(IIS) or Linux(Apache, Ngix)...

The best way to protect the files from being visted from `URL` is to set the upload path **outside** your webroot.And the file will be only accessiable by your server.

UPDATE: how to access files by user

Create a php file named readpdf.php.

```
header("Content-type:application/pdf");
//if you just want to show the file on broswer, delete the line below
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='downloaded.pdf'");
readfile("progit.pdf");
```

Read the file by visiting http://localhost/readpdf.php

Comment: and how user can access that files?

Comment: header("Content-type:application/pdf");  header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='downloaded.pdf'");  readfile("progit.pdf");

Comment: is the files still downloadable with downloader softw.. (like IDM)? thanks

Comment: the file is placed outside your web root, so users cannot download it by typing any url but by visiting your readpdf.php.