# Malicious code in automatically downloaded files?

Tags: security, csv, execute

I've done my research, but I want to double check:

Lets suppose I have a file like 'myfile.csv' on my website, which was acquired from a malicious source. Can any sort of executable server-side code be hidden in it?

If so, how do I prevent this?

Comment: What do you mean by "server-side code" in this context? What do you plan to do with these files? Certainly, if you rename them to *.php and make them available to your server to parse, bad things can happen.

Comment: if someone embeds some php for instance (or any other language) can it still "fire up" when the extension is a .csv? Under *any* circumstances?

Answer (score 1):

A CSV file would likely not be "executed" on the server side, rather it would simply be served up as-is.  You'll want to ensure that your web server's "handlers" are configured properly to prevent your CSV file from being processed by the PHP (or any other unintended) handler.

That said, you should if possible validate/sanitize all input into your application, even uploaded files e.g. CSV, especially if the content will later be accessible by other users.

Since you mentioned PHP, here is a link to some more info about Apache's Handlers.  IIS has similar functionality and I imagine most mature web servers have a way of handling requests for different file extensions differently. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/handler.html

If possible, I'd recommend storing your CSV files in a database (or really anywhere they cannot be accessed via a URL) and streaming them on-demand via an intermediary PHP file to clients.  Here is an example of that:  [Stream binary file from MySQL to download with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563069/stream-binary-file-from-mysql-to-download-with-php)